# Merge multiple times the same branch into another

Tags: git

Im using GIT. Let's say I have the branch development and production. I made some changes on development and merged to production. Everything worked as expected. Then I continue modifying development, and when I want to merge again with production, git says "Already up-to-date."... so how's the way to marge multiple times the same branch into another?

Comment: @Stavm not really a duplicate of that question. OP says he made new changes to development.

Comment: @DavidTG, already up to date means the branch you're trying to merge with has no changes in respect to one another. double check.

Comment: Please show the exact commands you entered rather than describing what you wanted git to do.  (I realize you may not remember what you did for the previous merge; but at least for the merge you're attempting now, what exactly is the command?)  Also, please try running `git status` on each branch and provide the output if you can.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you tried merging `production` to `development` and `production` did not evolve further, or at least you didn't fetch the changes. Merging a branch multiple times into another works fine if there were changes to merge.

Answer (score 6):

Actually yes you totally can, when you merge again it will bring over any commits that don't exist on production.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge